Help with infrared sauna circuit (remote power-on)
Good day, I am hoping to rely on you smart folks to help see if we can accomplish a specific goal. I have attached a pic of the circuit board from our infrared sauna. The sauna is in the basement of our home in Colorado (stays cold down there all year) and we would like to utilize a remote device to turn the sauna on in the morning (it takes about 45 mins to get up to desired temp).
I have tried a SwitchBot, but the button press on the sauna requires some type of human part. So, I opened the panel and found that the locations X, Y, and Z all turn the sauna on if you touch them with your bare finger or a wire. My next choice was to solder in a ZigBee smart relay to points X and Y to utilize my home wireless and cell phone. That did not work as the act of switching on/off did not activate the circuit to turn on the power (it appears to be haptic?). So, now I come to you brilliant folks to see if you have any other ideas before I just trot my old lazy self down 2 flight of stairs at 5 AM to start it up for the 6 AM roast. Caveat emptor, I am a very basic tinkerer so use small words :-)
Thanks in advance for your input. Cheers!


Before you continue (and zero offense intended): do you trust your "very basic tinkerer" skills and the advice of internet strangers to control a multi-kW heater in your home with no operator input? In a way that will certainly void whatever warranty (and liability) the manufacturer had?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sounds like you should phone an electrician to install something for you. If it burns down the house, at least it wasn't the fault of your tinkering so all is well on the insurance claim.

I appreciate the input! As always, the "newest" model of this sauna has the exact remote control via wireless that we need so it's not highly unusual for most modern saunas. The unit has multiple built-in protections that shut off the heaters and auto power down if left unattended for more than 30 minutes as well. All that said we have reached out to the manufacturer to see if we can get the new head unit that has the features we need without hacking into this one. Thanks all!

What is written on R16 (the black rectangular part at location 'Z')

Are you able to undo the nuts and show the other side of the board (and the back of the buttons)
